# prop('checked') never true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind my fake (but beautiful) checkboxes to real ones. Initially I can select all of them, but I can't unselect them. The Console always says: true, no matter how many times I click the fake checkboxes.

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).prev().prev().prop('checked')==true){
            $(this).prev().prev().prop('checked',false);
            console.log($(this).prev().prev().prop('checked'));
            $(this).removeClass('checkbox_checked');
            $(this).addClass('checkbox_clear');
        }
        else {
            $(this).prev().prev().prop('checked',true);
            console.log($(this).prev().prev().prop('checked'));
            $(this).removeClass('checkbox_clear');
            $(this).addClass('checkbox_checked');
            }
    });
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

PS: Here's the html.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The isChecked field is required." id="5_1" name="options[1].isChecked" value="true" type="checkbox"> 

<input name="options[1].isChecked" value="false" type="hidden">       

<label class="checkbox" for="5_1">Spring</label>
```

Comment: so many `$(this).prev().prev()` in that code. Show your HTML mark up.

Comment: is `$(this).prev().prev()` a checkbox

Comment: Yes, that is the checkbox. I have to use prev() twice because asp.net stubbornly places <input type=hidden> between the checkbox and label(fake checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the LABEL sets the checkbox to true or false. YOU are also setting the checkbox's checked to true or false. You do not have to do it! Let the browser do the checking!! It is always true, because you are causing it to be true.

All of that prev() stuff looks scary. I personally would just use the id.

```
$(document).on("click","label.checkbox", function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var isChecked = !$("#" + label.attr("for")).prop("checked");  //does not get checked until after label is fully clicked, hence the !
    label.toggleClass("checked", isChecked);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZKFS/